# Clarification of rulings on Carrionette

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It is my understanding that the individual card rulings on Gatherer are essentially clarifying comments.  i.e. they are "just" an application of the comprehensive rules to that specific card.

With that in mind, the rulings for [Carrionette](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCarrionette%5d) state:

> A creature with Protection from Creatures can’t be targeted by this card’s ability.

But, when Carrionette is in the graveyard, it is not a creature.  My guess is that rule 112 covers this somehow, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'creature' is not only a permanent type, but also a *card type*. [Rule 702.16a states](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 702.16a Protection is a static ability, written “Protection from [quality].”
>   ...
>   If the quality is a card type, subtype, or supertype, the ability applies to sources that are permanents with that card type, subtype, or supertype and to **any sources not on the battlefield that are of that card type, subtype, or supertype**. This is an exception to rule 109.2.
>
> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

so even though while a graveyarded Carrionette is not a creature by rule 109.2, it's still a card with type 'creature' which is sufficient for the protection ability.

Comment: It is not clear to me why 109.2 does not apply here. "Protection from creatures" is an ability that includes a card type and does not include the word "card". It sounds like 702.16a and 109.2 contradict each other.

Comment: 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

Comment: Because the expanded definition of the ability explicitly states that it applies to non-permanent objects.

Comment: Ah, the rules quote just didn't go long enough; I see that 702.16a mentions this specifically!

Comment: @GendoIkari I don't know *why* they made an exception to rule 109.2, but they did.

Comment: I'm clear now. I just needed to see that last sentence on the rule!

Comment: I didn't know rule 109.2 was *that* well-known, so I thought I'd only quote the directly relevant part for clarity.

Comment: Well the issue here is that the OP saying "when Carrionette is in the graveyard, it is not a creature" is only true because of rule 109.2. So whether the exact rule was known or not, the question only makes sense if asked by someone who knows how that works normally.

Comment: The exception is necessary because of tribal spells and auras, I suppose. If there was no exception to 109.2 for protection, they could still target a creature with protection from e.g. merfolk, or auras, respectively.

Comment: @GendoIkari thanks for pointing that out, it's slightly more convoluted than I originally thought (but still covered by the rules...).